# Python: Creating unknown number of variables using for-loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, product, keyword-argument

I want to create a generator that takes in any number of keyword arguments and it will return the product of the values (give as tuples as shown below).

I am having trouble avoiding hardcoding the for loop variables (`hardcoded_a`, `hardcoded_b`). In this scenario if I use more or less than two arguments it gives a `ValueError`. I don't care about hardcoding the 'okay' variables. How can I go about it so no matter how many items I pass to kwargs, I can still yield the product?

This is what I have written so far:

```
from itertools import product
def gen(**kwargs):
    options = {}
    [options.update({k: v}) for k, v in kwargs.iteritems()]
    for hardcoded_a, hardcoded_b in product(*(tuple(options.values()))):
       yield hardcoded_a, hardcoded_b

for okay_var1, okay_var2 in gen(dollar=(2, 20), hungry=(True, False)):
    print okay_var1, okay_var2
```

Comment: what is your objective? multiply all values of kwargs?

Comment: What should it print in your case?

Comment: @Milor123 I want to eventually yield a dictionary of the kwargs keys to a value making sure to cover all possible values

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output? I'm not getting what your goal is here exactly.

Comment: What would you like the generator to yield if someone passed it the arguments `arg1=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, `arg2=('a', 'b', 'c')` and `arg3=(True, False)`?

Comment: @TimS. currently it outputs `True 2` `True 20` `False 2` `False 20`

Comment: @af3ld Is that correct output? What was the input?  I think it would be best if you updated your question with a sample input and the expected output given that input.

Comment: @Reti43 `1 a True` `1 a False` `1 b True` `1 b False` ... `5 c True` `5 c False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the following:

```
def gen(**kwargs):
    options = {}
    [options.update({k: v}) for k, v in kwargs.iteritems()]
    for prod in product(*(tuple(options.values()))):
       yield dict(zip(options, prod))
```

or an even cleaner solution:

```
def gen(**kwargs):
    for prod in product(*kwargs.values()):
       yield dict(zip(kwargs, prod))
```

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your objective, the following should work:

```
from itertools import product

def gen(**kwargs):
    return product(*kwargs.values())
```

Example:

```
>>> print(list(gen(dollar=(2,20), hungry=(True,False))))
[(True, 2), (True, 20), (False, 2), (False, 20)]
```

It's worth noting, however, that `kwargs.values()` is not guaranteed to have a specific order. This will make sure they are ordered by the "natural ordering" (string comparison) of the keywords:

```
def gen2(**kwargs):
    return product(*map(lambda t:t[1],sorted(k.items())))
```

So now:

```
>>> print(list(gen2(dollar=(2,20), hungry=(True,False))))
[(2, True), (2, False), (20, True), (20, False)]
```